# Function having $n$ roots

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued smooth function from the set of real numbers has $n+1$ real roots, say $x_0,\cdots,x_n$. then is it always possible to write
$$
f(x)=g(x)(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n),
$$
for some function $g$?

I have a feeling it is possible, but unable to find an argument to prove.

Can someone please help with it. Thanks.

Comment: Can't we just define $g(x)$ by this equation?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess it could depend on if you require more conditions on $g$ (if you want continuity or more at the points $x_i$) but as it stands I agree with Dietrich Burde yeah.

Comment: Well I say that but $g$ defined by this equation outside of $\{x_i\}$ and extended by continuity to $\mathbb{R}$ (possible because $f(x_i) = 0$ and $f$ is differentiable at $x_i$) might just be smooth by smoothness of $f$ (most likely showable by induction).

Comment: Generally the answer is no (that is if you want $g$ to be continuous or even just bounded on closed intervals).  
 Consider $f(x) := 1 - e^{\sqrt{|x|}}$. The only root of $f$ is $0$, so let's suppose that there exists continuous $g$ such that $f(x) = xg(x)$. Thus $g(x) = f(x)/x$ for all $x\neq0$. And so: $$g(0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0 } g(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0 } f(x)/x = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0 } (1 - e^{\sqrt{|x|}})/x$$ where the limists are taken over $x \neq 0$.  
But the right hand side limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Notice that $f$ is not differentiable though. So maybe you want to consider only defferentiable functions $f$? For such $f$s there exists such a continuous $g$, at least if the roots of $f$ are distinct. I can prove it if you'd like.

Comment: @Jkbb I want to see the proof for the differentiable case. Maybe the problem of OP was that way.

Comment: Let's define $g(x) := f(x)/[(x-x_1)\cdot ... (x-x_n)]$ for $x$ not equal to any root (so it's only a partial function) and assume that roots are distinct. Then at point let's say $x_1$ we have $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_1} g(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_1} f(x)/[(x-x_1)\cdot ... (x-x_n)] = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_1} [f(x) - f(x_1)]/[(x-x_1)\cdot ... (x-x_n)] = f'(x_1)/[(x_1-x_2)\cdot...\cdot(x_1-x_n)]$$. We can reason in the same way for any root $x_i$ instead of $x_1$.
And so $g$ can be extended uniquely to a continuous function.

Comment: Notice that for multiple non-distinct roots a similar (but more complicated) reasoning will be correct if those roots are also roots of higher order derivatives of $f$.

Comment: What are the conditions for $g(x)$?  otherwise you can set $$g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{\prod_{i=0}^n (x-x_i)}$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241435/xf-smooth-rightarrow-f-smooth